# how to change dotnet core outgoing http request hostname from the default localhost

Tags: .net-core, ssl-certificate, httprequest, restsharp

I am able to successfully send requests to a sandbox via postman, given by a provider following their specs (see images below)

**Successful request** (see below)

[image: Pfx Cert]

In order to do that, aside from the respective headers and parameters (see image 2) I have to add a ssl/Tls certificate (.pfx) given that the server requires a 2 way handshake so it needs SSl client certificate:

[image]

**Authorization** (see below).

[image]

Headers (see below)
[image]

**Body** (see below)

[image]

Now, I am trying to do ir programatically using dotnet core 6, but I keep running into the same problem:

[image: Error]

And here is my code:

```
public static string GetAccessToken(IConfiguration _config)
    {
        string UserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USER_NAME");
        string Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PASSWORD");
        

        var client = new RestClient("https://connect2.xyz.com/auth/token");
       
        var request = new RestRequest();
        X509Certificate2 FullChainCertificate = new X509Certificate2("Path/to/Cert/cert.pfx", "test");
        client.Options.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { FullChainCertificate };
        client.Options.Proxy = new WebProxy("connect2.xyz.com");
        var restrequest = new RestRequest();
        restrequest.Method = Method.Get;
        restrequest.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        restrequest.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        restrequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        restrequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{UserName}:{Password}")));
        restrequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(restrequest);


        AccessTokenPointClickCare accessToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenPointClickCare>(response.Content);
        string strToken = accessToken.access_token;

        return strToken;
    }
```

Now, as the error seems to show, it has to do with the certificates (apparently), but I don't know if something in the code is wrong, or if I'm missing something, etc...

It is worth noting that this code did run in someone else's pc with the same set-up, but  of course with that person's own pfx, but for the rest, it is essentially the same, and not to mention that it **does** work on my postman.

Finally, as the title on this question, the only thing I can think it might also be affecting the request is the host. If I reference the postman, there is a field where I have to place the host name of the server `https://connect2.xyz.com/auth/token`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So made it work by changing to a new Windows 10. Researching in other Stackoverflow threads found the answer: [.NET CORE 5 '''HandshakeFailure'" when making HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904417/net-core-5-handshakefailure-when-making-https-request)

So I conclude it has to do with the cyphers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).